# My flatmate's Boston terrier is afraid of me

Tags: dogs, behavior, psychology, fear, socializing

I just moved in with my flatmate who already lived with her dog. I'm very dog friendly and have live with different dogs before, but is the first time that a dog is afraid of me. This only happens when we are alone, my flatmate arrives she is friendly and plays with me. This not only happens with me, but also with other people.

Why could this happen? How can I get her to trust me?

Answer (score 2):

Give her time to get used to you.  Don't approach her, and try not to stare at her, particularly face-on.  Instead, just get on with things as normal (trying not to make any loud noises) and let her approach you when she's ready.

If you want to speed things up a bit, check with her owner what's her favorite treat and have some of that ready to hand.  Don't approach her to give it to her, but try chucking it into the middle of the floor (not right at her!) and let her come and pick it up.